# Can we use CalendarApp to see events from a non-Google calendar that we are subscribed to (ex. Trello calendar)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, trello

Been using `CalendarApp` to help aggregate multiple Google calendars from different accounts into a single formatted spreadsheet which has been working beautifully. However, we want to incorporate more than just these calendars into the system and have been having trouble retrieving data from an imported calendar that we are subscribed to.

This calendar is from Trello (uses a *power-up* to create a calendar based on due dates) which provides a URL for us to subscribe to on Google. When I attempt to use the same `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)`, it doesn't appear to be able to access the event data and returns `null`.

For reference, here is the calendar id: *mp9si8iqi6uop4a20pr0r1v000dc9pcu@import.calendar.google.com*. The format is slightly different from Google calendars ending in *@group.calendar.google.com*.

Are we able to access calendar information from imported calendars like these? I tried `.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)` as well with no luck, but is there another way to view this data and include it in our calendar spreadsheet? Any help is appreciated!

#### Edit (by request)

If I was unclear, I tried the following:

```
calendarId = "mp9si8iqi6uop4a20pr0r1v000dc9pcu@import.calendar.google.com";
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
//and
calendarName = "Collab, Events & Special Buy";
CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName);
```

Only an issue with this calendar which is managed by Trello

Comment: Please add the the code which you've tried so far

Comment: Hey @ChucksKegscom I have just published an answer. Let me know if you have any issue with it. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @carlesgg97! We were able to locate the calendar this time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely get information from imported  calendars. Please try using the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  Logger.log(cal.getName());
  Logger.log(cal.getDescription());
  Logger.log(cal.getTimeZone());
  Logger.log(cal.getColor());
}
```

Run it, and navigate to View>Logs. You should be able to see the calendar's information. I recommend you also try the following:

#### Use the "Try this API" feature

- **List all your calendars and find the one you desire**. You should be able to find it, and also extract its id. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list
- **List the events on your calendar**. You only have to set the `calendarId` value that you have just retrieved and execute it. You should be able to see the events on your calendar. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list